# Generating a default value based on the current number of items from a Django database - Circular Import Problem

Tags: python, django, circular-dependency

I was working on a Django project but I can't really figure out on how can I avoid a circular import between a Django model and a custom python file `generators.py`

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.utils import timezone

from core.generators import make_id_number
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, fname, lname, password, **others):
        
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Please Provide Email Address!'))
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('Please Provide User Name!'))
        if not fname:
            raise ValueError(_('Please Provide First Name!'))
        if not lname:
            raise ValueError(_('Please Provide Last Name!'))
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            fname=fname,
            lname=lname,
            password=password,
            **others
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, fname, lname, password, **others):

        others.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        others.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        others.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if others.get('is_staff') is False:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have \'staff\' permissions!'))
        if others.get('is_active') is False:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must be active!'))
        if others.get('is_superuser') is False:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have \'superuser\' permissions!'))

        return self.create_user(email, username, fname, lname, password, **others)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'),max_length=150,unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('Username'),max_length=150,unique=True)
    fname = models.CharField(_('First Name'),max_length=150)
    mname = models.CharField(_('Middle Name'),max_length=150,null=True,blank=True)
    lname = models.CharField(_('Last Name'),max_length=150)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Joined'),default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('Last Login'),auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('Staff'),default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'),default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('Superuser'),default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'fname' , 'lname']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = (f'{self.fname} {self.lname}')
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.fname

class UserIdentification(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    id_number = models.BigIntegerField(_('ID Number'), default=make_id_number, unique=True)
    reg_code = models.CharField(_('Registration Code'), max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.user.username}-{self.id_number:09d}')
```

**core/generators.py**

```
import pytz

from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

from accounts.models import UserIdentification

# Generate a random password with the given length and given allowed_chars.
# The default value of allowed_chars does not have "I" or "O" or letters and digits that look similar to avoid confusion.
def make_random_password(length=12, allowed_chars='!@#$%^&*()_+-=abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'):
    return get_random_string(length, allowed_chars)


def make_id_number(local_tz=settings.TIME_ZONE):

    local_tz = pytz.timezone(local_tz)
    local_date = local_tz.normalize(timezone.now()).date()

    mm=int(local_date.month)
    dd=int(local_date.day)
    yy=int(local_date.year-2000)
    ccc=int(UserIdentification.objects.all().count())
    # ccc=0

    id_number=int(f'{mm:02d}{dd:02d}{yy:02d}{ccc+1:03d}')
    return id_number
```

As you can see this will surely result in a circular import problem, as I am importing `make_id_number` from `core/generators.py` that will query the database for the current number of users using the model `UserIdentification` from `accounts/models.py`, which in turn will ask the `core\generators.py` to generate an id number.

I would greatly appreciate anyone who can give me a solution, a hint, or a tutorial on how can I avoid this.

Comment: not specify `default=make_id_number` in the model, but move it to the overriding  `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` function

Comment: @caot thanks for the idea. I will try that out later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got it.**

Kudos to @caot for giving me a heads up. What I did was modified the UserIdentificaton Model - removed `default=make_id_number` and added a `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` functions.

**account/models.py**

```
...
class UserIdentification(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    id_number = models.BigIntegerField(_('ID Number'), unique=True, blank=True)
    reg_code = models.CharField(_('Registration Code'), max_length=150, unique=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.user.username}-{self.id_number:09d}')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ccc = UserIdentification.objects.all().count()+1
        self.id_number = make_id_number(ccc)
        super(UserIdentification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

also updated `make_id_number` function from `core/generators.py`

**core/generators.py**

```
def make_id_number(ccc, local_tz=settings.TIME_ZONE):

    local_tz = pytz.timezone(local_tz)
    local_date = local_tz.normalize(timezone.now()).date()

    mm=int(local_date.month)
    dd=int(local_date.day)
    yy=int(local_date.year-2000)
    
    return int(f'{mm:02d}{dd:02d}{yy:02d}{ccc:03d}')
```

There may be a more optimized answer to this. But I sticking to this for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to avoid circular imports in python

Only import the module, not from the module

In models.py:  `import core.generators`

In generators.py: `import accounts.models`

Comment: then how can I query the model?

Answer (score 0):

The simple easiest fix for such circular import in your code, is to import `UserIdentification` inside your `make_id_number` function in your `core/generators.py` file. this will break the module circular import, and only imports it inside the function scope when it is called.

so your file should look like this:

```
# core/generators.py

import pytz

from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

###### Remove it from here #####

# Generate a random password with the given length and given allowed_chars.
# The default value of allowed_chars does not have "I" or "O" or letters and digits that look similar to avoid confusion.
def make_random_password(length=12, allowed_chars='!@#$%^&*()_+-=abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'):
    return get_random_string(length, allowed_chars)


def make_id_number(local_tz=settings.TIME_ZONE):
    ##### Import it here #####
    from accounts.models import UserIdentification

    local_tz = pytz.timezone(local_tz)
    local_date = local_tz.normalize(timezone.now()).date()

    mm=int(local_date.month)
    dd=int(local_date.day)
    yy=int(local_date.year-2000)
    ccc=int(UserIdentification.objects.all().count())
    # ccc=0

    id_number=int(f'{mm:02d}{dd:02d}{yy:02d}{ccc+1:03d}')
    return id_number
```

Comment: This may be logical at first look but it will probably still throw the same problem because `accounts\model.py` directly accesses the `make_id_number` function of `core\generators.py`  when I added it as a `default` to the `id_number` field of the `UserIdentification` model.